# Kotlin okhttp parse error to recycle view

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

I have a json file which contain some data I am trying to parse this data into kotlin in array using modal class and display in recycler view but unable to get it, the app keep crashing while I start the activity.
The Json data what I want to parse

> Member Bank API: [MemberBankModel(bankName=Alliance Bank, memberBankAccNumber=11111111), MemberBankModel(bankName=Bank Simpanan Nasional, memberBankAccNumber=222222222)] 
> Log from Log.d("Member Bank API","${saveBankResponseModel.data!!.memberBank}")

Activity.kt

```
 okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful) {
                    saveBankResponseModel = json.decodeFromString(
                        response.body!!.string()
                    )
                    Log.d("Member Bank API","${saveBankResponseModel.data!!.memberBank}")
                    val noBankView = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.nobank_layout)
                    newRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
                    noBankView.visibility = View.GONE
                    newRecyclerView.apply {
                        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MyWalletActivity)
                        adapter = saved_bank_adapter(saveBankResponseModel.data!!.memberBank)
                    }
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                mHandler.post {
                    println(e)
                }
            }
        })
```

data Class

```
@Serializable
data class SaveBankResponseModel(
    val responseCode:Int,
    val msgType:String,
    val message:List<String>,
    val data:SaveBankDataModel? = null
)

@Serializable
data class SaveBankDataModel(
    val accountHolder:AccountModel,
    val memberBank:List<MemberBankModel>
)

@Serializable
data class AccountModel(
    val name:String,
)
@Serializable
data class MemberBankModel(
    val bankName:String,
    val memberBankAccNumber:String
)
```

RecycleAdapter

```
class saved_bank_adapter(private val bankList: List<MemberBankModel>): RecyclerView.Adapter<saved_bank_adapter.BankViewHolder>() {

    private var selectedItemPosition: Int = 0
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): BankViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.withdrawbank_layout, parent, false)
        return BankViewHolder(itemView)

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: BankViewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") position: Int) {
        val currentItem = bankList[position]

            holder.itemName.text = currentItem.bankName

            holder.itemAccNum.text = currentItem.memberBankAccNumber
}
```

Can anyone please help me to check what step I'm doing wrong, I'm new to Kotlin API call

Error I get...

> 2022-08-22 16:44:06.584 8526-8632/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
> Process: com.example.app, PID: 8526
> android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: Where does the app crash? Can you post the error message?

Comment: It show a FATAL EXCEPTION when doing the request.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see memberBankAccNumber field value is an integer in your API response, But you have declared that build as String, So the error is here.

```
val memberBankAccNumber:String
```

Replace this with

```
val memberBankAccNumber:Int
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, unfortunately my app still crash and I'm getting a FATAL EXCEPTION when doing the request.

Comment: Can you please add crash logs?

Comment: I fixed it, the error was caused by a small mistake which is I didn't add mHandler.post, thanks for the answer, btw I also improved my code based on your comment